# How can I fix my CSS drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My `nav` bar menu has 2 problems

1. text background color doesnt fit to the `nav` bar background which means there is some empty space around it
2. When I click on the menu instead of opening the drop down menu outside the `nav` bar it will open it within the nav bar and streches the navbar background color

https://ibb.co/cR5Zt7
https://ibb.co/mvCKRS

```css
body{
 padding-top: 20px;
}

#navbar{
 /*background color*/
 background-color:#498AA2;
 size:100% !important;
 background-position:inherit;
}
/*change color top menu*/
#text{
 background-color:#C11D1F;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scaleable=no">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
  <div class="container">
     <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand" id="text">my site</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- drop down menu-->
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="text">Men<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Tshirt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">pants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">shoes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">accessories</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. You can only select one accepted answer. You won't be able to do this if two separate people answer each of your two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

for problem 1, to make `men` dropdown as same style as `mysite`, you can use,

```
<li class="dropdown navbar-brand" id="text">
```

for problem 2, adding these three styles to `.dropdown-menu`

```
#navbar .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

sample like

---

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#navbar {
  /*background color*/
  background-color: #498AA2;
  size: 100% !important;
  background-position: inherit;
}


/*change color top menu*/

#text {
  background-color: #C11D1F;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-position: center;
}

#navbar .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scaleable=no">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand" id="text">my site</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- drop down menu-->
        <li class="dropdown navbar-brand" id="text">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="text">Men<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Tshirt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">pants</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">shoes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">accessories</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: [Please be VERY cautious using !important](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used)

Comment: Not need if you are include the main css after including bootstrap css, it just overriding the bootstrap default class

Comment: Nope, the bootstrap selector `.navbar .dropdown-menu` is more specific than `.dropdown-menu`. Use specificy to your advantage either `#navbar .dropdown-menu` or `.navbar ul.dropdown-menu` will work.

Comment: @JonP yes you are right, that way will also work... updated my code, plz check it

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys for your kind reply, aswin you solved my second problem but first still there and if you run it here the red is smaller than blue background.technicaly idont want any border or gap between red and blue
many thanks